# Yii2 как получить значение cookie средствами фреймворка?

Tags: php, yii2, cookie

Есть кука advanced-frontend
как получит ее средствами фреймворка ?

```
<pre>
    раз
    <? print_r(Yii::$app->request->cookies)?>
</pre>

<pre>
    два
    <? print_r($_COOKIE)?>
</pre>
```

в результате в **$_COOKIE** она есть , а в **Yii::$app->request->cookies** нет ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы же доку прочитали не только про то как получить куку из запроса, но и следующий параграф про [валидацию кук](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-sessions-cookies#cookie-validation) ?

Answer (score 2):

Напишу то, что написано в [доках](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-sessions-cookies#cookie-validation). Чтоб был ответ.

Во время записи и чтения кук через компоненты `request` и `response`, фреймворк предоставляет автоматическую валидацию, которая обеспечивает защиту кук от модификации на стороне клиента. Это достигается за счет подписи каждой куки секретным ключом, позволяющим приложению распознать куку, которая была модифицирована на клиентской стороне. В таком случае кука **НЕ БУДЕТ** доступна через свойство `cookie collection` компонента `request`

Валидация кук защищает только от их модификации. Если валидация не была пройдена, получить доступ к кукам все еще можно через глобальную переменную `$_COOKIE`. Это связано с тем, что дополнительные пакеты и библиотеки могут манипулировать куками без вызова валидации, которую обеспечивает *Yii*.

При использовании валидации кук необходимо указать значение свойства `yii\web\Request::$cookieValidationKey` в конфигурации приложении. Это свойство будет использовано для генерации вышеупомянутого секретного ключа.

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'fill in a secret key here',
        ],
    ],
];
```

**По-умолчанию валидация кук включена**. Её можно отключить, установив свойство `yii\web\Request::$enableCookieValidation` в `false`

---

P.S. Куки, которые напрямую читаются/пишутся через `$_COOKIE` и `setcookie()` **НЕ БУДУТ** валидироваться.

Comment: тут вопрос то  наверное в том, что он куку с фронта устанавливает не подписанную, а request невалидную просто игнорирует и не отдает